# ajaxcontroltoolkit combobox listitem does not show in proper place

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using a ajaxcontroltoolkit combobox  but the listitems are not displayed in the proper place. The listitem is displayed far below the textbox. How to change it?

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="cbItems" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" MaxLength="0"
                CssClass="WindowsStyle" AppendDataBoundItems="false" RenderMode="Block">
   <asp:ListItem>Fox</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>1231</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>dsgadsg</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>4rjh56jh</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ComboBox>
```

Please any idea or suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: please provide sample markup/error messages to further elaborate the problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove `CssClass="WindowsStyle"` and test your web application. this is due to style sheet classes. Change them accordingly.